# How do i input any number/alphabet/character in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, integer

how can i get it to quit if i input any value/character other than 1

Comment: you can always use an `else` statement to `exit`!

Comment: It will "break" of its own accord if you enter anything other than an integer due to a ValueError exception during the *int()* conversion attempt

Answer (score 0):

```
   import sys
   while True:
       i = input('Please enter confirm (input 1) to proceed with     
       username and password creation (or any to quit):\n')
       if i.isnumeric() == 1:
           print("Generating username and password....")
           break
       else:
           sys.exit()
```

Comment: The question is checking specifically for a value of 1. This code will execute the *print()* if the input is any numeric string

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, your `if` statement, `if i.isnumeric() == 1:` runs if the value of `i` is _**any**_ number! Because, when you write `i.isnumeric() == 1`, it evalutes the `1` as `True`. Therefore, even if I enter `2` or `1234567890`, it will display `Generating username and password....`.